# RegKey Setvalue not working across different Windows Versions

Tags: c#, windows, registrykey

here is my problem:

I have an application written in C#. The application is running as a 32Bit Process.
Inside of the application I want to kill the process `explorer.exe`
Here is how i do that:

```cs
private void killExplorer()
{
  try
  {
     RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine;

     regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\", true);
     regKey.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 0);


     var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
     Console.Write("Killing Explorer... ");
     foreach (var process in processes)
     {
        process.Kill();
        process.WaitForExit();
     }
     Console.WriteLine("Done");
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     log.Debug(ex);
     Console.WriteLine(ex);
  }
}
```

If i dont set the RegKey AutorestartShell to 0 then Explorer will instantly start up again.

Ok now, i tested this and it works fine on my development machine(W10 x64).
My application has to work from Windows XP up to W10. Killing the explorer only works on W10 x64 and W10 x32.

Explorer automatically restarts On W7 and W8. And the regKey is never set, even though it exists.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Win10 is different from previous versions, it no longer auto-restarts Explorer.exe.  So the most obvious explanation is that writing AutoRestartShell just never worked correctly.  Which is normal for a 32-bit app, look at HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/etc...  Use RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey() to select the correct view.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your reply. I will give that a try. Would this then also work when i test it on a 32Bit architecture? Or would i have to use different Path for 32Bit?

Comment: Use Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem to know what view to select.

Comment: @HansPassant But the path is the same?

Comment: HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/.. is not the same path.  Be sure to understand how [the registry redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector) works so you can understand what OpenBaseKey does.

Comment: Yes i meant that the path is the same for both 32 and 64 bit key. Not the same as the one i posted.

Just to be clear. The path HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node works on both types of architectures.

Thank you so much btw!